# How to convert two rows in one using Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table named COMPANY_DETAILS which has total 5 columns

```
ID  NAME     REVENUE_YEAR  TOTAL_REVENUE  TOTAL_ASSET
100 ABC CORP 2015          50000          30000 
100 ABC CORP 2016          60000          40000
200 XYZ CORP 2015          85000          60000
200 XYZ CORP 2016          75000          55000
```

How can I get the  below table pattern through SQL Query?

```
ID  NAME     REVENUE_YEAR15  TOTAL_REVENUE15  TOTAL_ASSET15 REVENUE_YEAR16  TOTAL_REVENUE16  TOTAL_ASSET16
100 ABC CORP 2015            50000            30000         2016            60000          40000
200 XYZ CORP 2015            85000            60000         2016            75000          55000
```

Please help me on that. I am using Oracle 11g.

Comment: "Write me a query to do X" is not a question.

Comment: Please help me on this.how can i get the desire output

Comment: I can give you a hint . You can use lead() or lag() functions . Search or that in oracle docs or any other source.

Comment: thanks kartik.. i used lead() function. It's works..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
select ID, NAME, 2015 REVENUE_YEAR15 ,
        SUM ( CASE WHEN REVENUE_YEAR = 2015 THEN TOTAL_REVENUE 
                        ELSE 0 END) TOTAL_REVENUE15,
        SUM ( CASE WHEN REVENUE_YEAR = 2015 THEN TOTAL_ASSET 
                        ELSE 0 END) TOTAL_REVENUE15,  
        2016 REVENUE_YEAR16 ,              
        SUM ( CASE WHEN REVENUE_YEAR = 2016 THEN TOTAL_REVENUE 
                        ELSE 0 END) TOTAL_REVENUE16,
        SUM ( CASE WHEN REVENUE_YEAR = 2016 THEN TOTAL_ASSET 
                        ELSE 0 END) TOTAL_REVENUE16    
FROM   COMPANY_DETAILS GROUP BY ID,NAME;
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/09f468/3)